# Do ... While System.Media.SoundPlayer() is in use

Tags: c#, soundplayer

I have been trying to display text on my Console Application while a sound file is currently playing, lyrics as an example. How is the best way to do it?

```
struct Music 
{
        public
            void PlaySong() {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\MyPC\Music\MoreMusic\songsample.wav";
            player.Load();
            player.PlaySync();
        }
}

class Program
{


        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Music music;
            do
            {
                //Display Lyrics
            } while (true); //as the song progresses


         }

}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the lyrics to pop up as the same plays word by word in sync with the song? Or just all at once?

Comment: using the lyrics example, yes. As the song progresses the lyrics should pop up, maybe with timings in between but I got the hang of this part.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89845/MP-CDG-Karaoke-Player

Comment: This might be able to lead you in the right direction, not a console application but should hopefully help

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for you help.

Comment: Cool, post your answer so the next person with the same problem can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the PlaySync with Play

```
    struct Music 
{
        public
            void PlaySong() {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\MyPC\Music\MoreMusic\songsample.wav";
            player.Load();
            player.Play();
        }
}
```